# How to use secure websocket by using Poco in C++

Tags: c++, poco, wss

I am trying to use secure websocket by using C++ to connect echo.websocket.org.
It works in javascript at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

My solution is to use Poco libraries and my code looks like following.

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();

Poco::Net::Context context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession Client("echo.websocket.org", 443, &context);

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text", Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request.set("origin", "https://www.websocket.org");
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;

try
{
    Poco::Net::WebSocket webSocket(Client, request, response);

    std::string str = "Hello!";

    char receiveBuff[256];

    int len = webSocket.sendFrame(str.data(), str.size(), Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
    std::cout << "Sent bytes " << len << std::endl;
    int flags = 0;

    int rlen = webSocket.receiveFrame(receiveBuff, 256, flags);
    std::cout << "Received bytes " << rlen << std::endl;
    std::cout << receiveBuff << std::endl;

    webSocket.close();
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
}
```

But I get SSL Exception with this code.
Can anybody help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you debug and tell which instruction is throwing the exception?

Comment: Thanks!
Exception is thrown at the point of creating webSocket.
Poco::Net::WebSocket webSocket(Client, request, response);

Comment: Is it possible to step inside? Since it looks like you need to build the library anyway, you should be able to have a debug build and find out where in the library something goes wrong by stepping inside.

Comment: I have found the reason is in certification.
I am managed to find a [working example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite).
But another problem is that I can't figured how it worked out.
For example, pem file is used for certification, but I don't know how that pem file is used in the project.